# javascript problems server side

Tags: javascript, server-side

I have a php script that uses some css/javascript tabs, they work on my local server but not when i upload to my online server.

Just wondering if anyone knows why this might be the case? All the paths are correct, its basically an identical setup.

I would be grateful to find out some reasons why the error appears on the server side, i thought javascript executed on the client side?

Any help is much appreciated.

Ke

Comment: Can you post a link to the online server?

Comment: We can't help without the actual codes.

Comment: its joomla community builder, the tabs arent working, ive narrowed it down to mootools not loading, any idea why it might not load, it doesnt seem to be loading in the source at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the permissions on your mootools lib if it seems to not be loading at all.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side.  If it works when served locally, but not when served online chances are really, really good there is a path error or a missing file.  I use Firefox with the web developer addon which will show you all the js from a page (and show if there are js errors on the page).